# Alias criado em shell-script não funciona

Tags: linux, ubuntu, shell-script, alias

Estou tentando criar um aliás utilizando um shell-script, porém ao finalizar a execução o alias desaparece.

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "Configurando ambiente...";
mkdir -p ~/.dna

alias teste="node $HOME/.dna/start.js"
echo "Exibindo alias criado";
alias teste
```

O código acima cria o alias, pois logo abaixo do último echo ele é exibido, mas ao tentar executar o comando `teste` no terminal ele não encontra o comando.

Caso eu execute o trecho `alias teste="node $HOME/.dna/start.js"` diretamente no terminal o alias funciona.

Alguém sabe o motivo disso ocorrer e possui alguma solução de contorno?

Obrigado.

Comment: Pessoal porque fora de escopo? É uma dúvida de programação.

Comment: Provavelmente o alias não está sendo salvo,ele existe apenas na sessão que está atualmente,  dá dando um `export`?

Comment: Não tá dando export não @Tuxpilgrim .

Comment: Dá uma olhada nisso: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2197461/how-to-set-an-alias-inside-a-bash-shell-script-so-that-is-it-visible-from-the-ou

Comment: Obrigado @Tuxpilgrim era exatamente isso que eu precisava. Se quiser traduzir para a comunidade brasileira eu vou marcar como correta a resposta. Obrigado. ;)

Comment: Opa, que ótimo que deu certo! Resolveu usando o `source` ou o `shopt -s expand_aliases`?

Comment: @Tuxpilgrim utilizando o `source` mesmo.

Comment: Pronto, quando puder aceitar a resposta @Hiago!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O alias que está criando está apenas dentro do shell que está executando o script, para persistir os aliases que está criando é precisar usar o `source ./script.sh`.Quando executa o comando `source` o conteúdo do arquivo vai ser executado no shell atual, e os aliases vão ser persistidos no ambiente.

Obs¹: Resposta baseada [nessa postagem do SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2197461/how-to-set-an-alias-inside-a-bash-shell-script-so-that-is-it-visible-from-the-ou).

Obs²: Mais sobre o comando `source` ver [esse link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/source-command-in-linux-with-examples/).